# check if div contains text from an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this basic code which hides the closest tr if .foo contains a string:

```
$('.foo:contains("blah")').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').hide();
 });
```

but the time has come that "blah" is not the only string I need to check for, I realise I now need to use an array but not sure how.

I took a wild guess and tried:

```
var arr = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar'];

$('.foo:contains("+arr[]+")').each(function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').hide();
     });
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, however you'll need to loop over your array as well to check each value.

```
var arr = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar'];

var i=0;
for (; i<arr.length; i++) {
    $(".foo:contains('"+arr[i]+"')").each(function() {
         $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will tag as answer when time allows.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar'];

$('.foo').each(function() {
    if($.inArray($(this).text(),arr)!==-1 ) {
      $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    }
     });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Or, with filter(): http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
$( ".foo" )
  .filter(function( ) {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(),arr)!==-1;
  }).closest('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work (although there are probably much better ways of doing it).

```
var arr = ["John", "Jane", "Mike", "Ted"];
arr.forEach(function(val){
   $(".foo:contains('" + val + "')").each(function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: `val` needs to be in seperate quotes inside the selector for `.foo:contains` in order to run properly.